# Thickening a tree always gives a disc

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Armstrong's Basic Topology. In Chapter 1 introduction, he claims that thickening the tree and the dual tree of a polyhedron will give out a disc, just like the figure below: [image]

I have a question that does the disc here refer to the circle as it normally does? If it is, how is it a disc? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A disc here is meant to refer to the unit disc in the plane, $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2<1\}$. (This is an open disc, but the author might have a closed disc in mind.)

To say that the thickened tree "is a disc" means that it is homeomorphic to a disk. Probably the point here is that the thickened tree, just like the tree itself, is contractible.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I understand now.